# RMagick convert ps to pdf

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, postscript

When I convert a PS file to PDF, it works fine on the local machine, but on the production server, it adds margin to the page, as if I selected Scale to Fit instead of Scale: 100% from the Mac OSX Preview print settings. How do i prevent this? Currently, I'm doing:

```
Magick::ImageList::new('cool.ps').write('cool.pdf') # only works on local machine
```

UPDATE: I solved this! See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

```
system("gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sPAPERSIZE=letter -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
        -sOutputFile='cool.pdf' 'cool.ps'")
```

- `-dSAFER` (readonly) prevents the input file from being changed.
- `-dBATCH` quits Ghostscript automatically.
- `-dNOPAUSE` continues automatically after each page conversion.

I realized that you can also use the command `ps2pdf` (which seems nicer) instead of `gs`, but the above worked fine, so I kept it because I have other more important things to do, and I cannot easily deploy to and test on production.

### How I came about this solution

First, I figured out that I could [use `ghostscript` to convert PostScript (PS) files to PDF](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#ghostscript).

So, I tried using Ghostscript but got the same result. (In hindsight, I learned this is because ImageMagic delegates PS & PDF formats to Ghostscript anyhow.)

After further examination of the production-server generated PDF, I realized that actually the page size of the PDF generated by the production server (vs. that of the PDF generated by my local machine) was slightly larger (In hindsight, I think it was a4.), thus, causing the addition of margin, haha. :)

I thought to myself, why is the production server using a different page size? ...

Aha! The Ghostscript configuration files (Actually, I soon thereafter learned that they're called [Ghostscript initialization files](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/cvs/Psfiles.htm#General).) on the production server must be specifying a different default [Ghostscript page size](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/gnu/7.05/Use.htm#Paper_size).

Alright, who's the nincompoop that decided (when installing Ghostscript on the production server) to override the default paper size to a4?

Fortunately, since I don't have production access, I could set it explicitly with `-sPAPERSIZE=legal`, but I wasn't done investigating things...

On my local machine, I did a `man gs` and then searched for "init" by typing `/init` and then enter. Then, `n` & `N` to cycle through the results. I saw `gs_init.ps`, so I quit `q` and did:

```
sudo find / -name gs_init.ps
```

I got:

```
/opt/local/share/ghostscript/8.71/Resource/Init/gs_init.ps
/opt/local/var/macports/software/ghostscript/8.71_3/opt/local/share/ghostscript/8.71/Resource/Init/gs_init.ps
```

I `cat`ted the second result (since I remembered installing ImageMagick with MacPorts, although if I had to do it again, I'd probably install ImageMagick from source or with HomeBrew instead). I searched for `PAPERSIZE` and found:

```
% Optionally choose a default paper size other than U.S. letter.
% The default page size for many devices is set at compile time to 
% letter, but this can be changed to A4 although this is rarely done.  
% Some devices such as bbox have a different default page size,
% and should not be set to A4 or letter.
% When ghostscript is used in countries that use the international
% standard page size A4 rather than US letter, the page size of 
% devices that default to letter or A4 can be changed by setting
% DEFAULTPAPERSIZE.
% /DEFAULTPAPERSIZE (a4) def
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure, but you can find out whether converting **from ps** or whether converting **to pdf** is the problem by trying another image format.  Png won't have extra borders, so if it gets them in this example, you know converting from ps is the problem.

```
Magick::ImageList::new('cool.ps').write('cool.png')
```

Comment: Great idea. I'll try this and report back.

Comment: Thanks for the idea & encouragement. That got me to follow through with this and find a solution. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568678/rmagick-convert-ps-to-pdf/5187139#5187139). I couldn't just simply convert to PNG because I wanted a multiple-page document.